# SQL Server CASE Statement in side where clause switch operator

Tags: sql-server

I have a case in where clause, I need to change the operator used based on `@MyStatus` value. I did some thing like this, but it's not working

```
......
WHERE 
    CASE @WorkStatus 
        WHEN 1 
            THEN X.EarlyEnd < GETDATE()
        WHEN 2
            THEN X.EarlyEnd = GETDATE()
        WHEN 3
            THEN X.EarlyEnd > GETDATE()
    END)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just in case you don't have to use the `CASE` statement at all, the following will work, too:

```
...
WHERE(@WorkStatus = 1 AND [X].[EarlyEnd] < GETDATE())
     OR (@WorkStatus = 2 AND [X].[EarlyEnd] = GETDATE())
     OR (@WorkStatus = 3 AND [X].[EarlyEnd] > GETDATE());
```

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server has a [case expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql) not a statement.  The difference being an expression returns a value, whereas a statement [controls flow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_flow).

Your case expression needs to return a value that can be tested.  Example:

```
...
WHERE
    CASE 
        WHEN @WorkStatus = 1 AND X.EarlyEnd < GETDATE() THEN 1
        WHEN @WorkStatus = 2 AND X.EarlyEnd = GETDATE() THEN 1
        WHEN @WorkStatus = 3 AND X.EarlyEnd > GETDATE() THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END = 1  -- Test value returned by expresssion.
...
```

**Edit**: [@OnkelToob's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48583840/2572928) is better in this case.  He correctly spotted you don't need a case expression at all.